# ASP.NET MVC Versioning Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, .net-3.5

I have a web application with a couple different sub-webs that use MVC.  The problem I'm running into is that two of the sub webs use different MVC versions.  One was recently upgraded to use the 1.0 version, and one is stuck on an earlier preview version.

After upgrading one of the sub-webs to 1.0, the other web that is using the preview version fails with the following error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextWrapper2' from assembly 'System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I suspect that the problem is due to the fact that both the 1.0 version and preview versions of the System.Web.Abstractions DLL are labeled as version 3.5.0.0, but actually contain different classes.  So, when the preview app references System.Web.Abstractions, it gets the already loaded MVC 1.0 version instead of the preview version that is in its bin directory.

Is there any way I can force the runtime to load the assembly twice as if they were two different versions even though they are actually labeled with the same version number?  I was looking into using the  tag in my web config, but couldn't quite grok exactly how I would use that to do this, or if it would even achieve what I need to do here.

Comment: Do you really need two versions running side-by-side, will unintall the previous version take care of yoru issue?

Comment: I really do need both versions running side by side - there are breaking changes in the 1.0 version that cause code written against the preview version to no longer work.  I could convert the app using the preview version to use 1.0, but I'd rather avoid doing that right now if possible.

Comment: I ended up just converting the app to MVC 1.0.  It had to be done eventually anyways, but I'd still be interested in knowing if there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue. Most of our applications use MVC 3.0. We are using a content management system that uses MVC 1.0. We had a compatibility issue because we were trying to referece one of the application components in the content management system. When we put both versions of MVC into the GAC, this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could put **System.Web.Abstractions.dll**, **System.Web.Mvc.dll** and **System.Web.Routing.dll** assemblies with corresponding versions (from MVC preview and from MVC 1.0) in ~/bin folders of each of your sub-webs.

UPDATED:

Try removing this from web.config of your App using ASP.NET MVC Preview version:

```
<system.web>
    <assemblies>
        <!--<add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
    </assemblies>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  3.5 SP1 is installed on the servers, so MVC 1.0 is there for all apps already.  The app that needs the preview version has the preview bins in its /bin folder, but it seems they are being ignored because SP1 puts the 1.0 bins in the GAC (and the preview bins have the same version number)

Comment: Did you try removing <add assembly .. /> for Abstractions/Mvc/Routing from web.config/system.web/compilation/assemblies section for Application using ASP.NET MVC Preview?

Comment: @eu-ge-ne - yes, just tried that and it didn't have any effect.  Still getting the same error message as before.